# Multi-feature causal CNN - Keras implementation

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, lstm

I'm currently using a basic LSTM to make regression predictions and I would like to implement a causal CNN as it should be computationally more efficient.

I'm struggling to figure out how to reshape my current data to fit the causal CNN cell and represent the same data/timestep relationship as well as what the dilation rate should be set at.

My current data is of this shape: `(number of examples, lookback, features)` and here's a basic example of the LSTM NN I'm using right now.

```
lookback = 20   #  height -- timeseries
n_features = 5  #  width  -- features at each timestep

# Build an LSTM to perform regression on time series input/output data
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(units=256, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(lookback, n_features)))
model.add(Activation('elu'))

model.add(LSTM(units=256, return_sequences=True))
model.add(Activation('elu'))

model.add(LSTM(units=256))
model.add(Activation('elu'))

model.add(Dense(units=1, activation='linear'))

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')

model.fit(X_train, y_train,
          epochs=50, batch_size=64,
          validation_data=(X_val, y_val),
          verbose=1, shuffle=True)

prediction = model.predict(X_test)
```

I then created a new CNN model (although not causal as the `'causal'` padding is only an option for `Conv1D` and not `Conv2D`, per Keras documentation. If I understand correctly, by having multiple features, I need to use `Conv2D`, rather than `Conv1D` but then if I set `Conv2D(padding='causal')`, I get the following error - `Invalid padding: causal`)

Anyways, I was also able to fit the data with a new shape `(number of examples, lookback, features, 1)` and run the following model using the `Conv2D` Layer:

```
lookback = 20   #  height -- timeseries
n_features = 5  #  width  -- features at each timestep

 model = Sequential()
            model.add(Conv2D(128, 3, activation='elu', input_shape=(lookback, n_features, 1)))
model.add(MaxPool2D())
model.add(Conv2D(128, 3, activation='elu'))
model.add(MaxPool2D())
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')

model.fit(X_train, y_train,
          epochs=50, batch_size=64,
          validation_data=(X_val, y_val),
          verbose=1, shuffle=True)

prediction = model.predict(X_test)
```

However, from my understanding, this does not propagate the data as causal, rather just the entire set `(lookback, features, 1)` as an image.

Is there any way to either reshape my data to fit into a `Conv1D(padding='causal')` Layer, with multiple features or somehow run the same data and input shape as `Conv2D` with `'causal'` padding?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that you can have **causal padding** with **dilation** for any number of input features. Here is the solution I would propose.

The [TimeDistributed layer](https://keras.io/layers/wrappers/#TimeDistributed) is key to this.

From Keras Documentation: **"This wrapper applies a layer to every temporal slice of an input. The input should be at least 3D, and the dimension of index one will be considered to be the temporal dimension."**

For our purposes, we want this layer to apply "something" to each feature, so we move the features to the temporal index, which is 1.

Also relevant is the [Conv1D documentation](https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/#Conv1D).

Specifically about channels: **"The ordering of the dimensions in the inputs.  "channels_last" corresponds to inputs with shape  (batch, steps, channels) (default format for temporal data in Keras)"**

```
from tensorflow.python.keras import Sequential, backend
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import GlobalMaxPool1D, Activation, MaxPool1D, Flatten, Conv1D, Reshape, TimeDistributed, InputLayer

backend.clear_session()
lookback = 20
n_features = 5

filters = 128

model = Sequential()
model.add(InputLayer(input_shape=(lookback, n_features, 1)))
# Causal layers are first applied to the features independently
model.add(Permute(dims=(2, 1)))  # UPDATE must permute prior to adding new dim and reshap
model.add(Reshape(target_shape=(n_features, lookback, 1)))
# After reshape 5 input features are now treated as the temporal layer 
# for the TimeDistributed layer

# When Conv1D is applied to each input feature, it thinks the shape of the layer is (20, 1)
# with the default "channels_last", therefore...

# 20 times steps is the temporal dimension
# 1 is the "channel", the new location for the feature maps

model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv1D(filters, 3, activation="elu", padding="causal", dilation_rate=2**0)))
# You could add pooling here if you want. 
# If you want interaction between features AND causal/dilation, then apply later
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv1D(filters, 3, activation="elu", padding="causal", dilation_rate=2**1)))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv1D(filters, 3, activation="elu", padding="causal", dilation_rate=2**2)))


# Stack feature maps on top of each other so each time step can look at 
# all features produce earlier
model.add(Permute(dims=(2, 1, 3)))  # UPDATED to fix issue with reshape
model.add(Reshape(target_shape=(lookback, n_features * filters)))  # (20 time steps, 5 features * 128 filters)
# Causal layers are applied to the 5 input features dependently
model.add(Conv1D(filters, 3, activation="elu", padding="causal", dilation_rate=2**0))
model.add(MaxPool1D())
model.add(Conv1D(filters, 3, activation="elu", padding="causal", dilation_rate=2**1))
model.add(MaxPool1D())
model.add(Conv1D(filters, 3, activation="elu", padding="causal", dilation_rate=2**2))
model.add(GlobalMaxPool1D())
model.add(Dense(units=1, activation='linear'))

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')

model.summary()
```

**Final Model Summary**

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
reshape (Reshape)            (None, 5, 20, 1)          0         
_________________________________________________________________
time_distributed (TimeDistri (None, 5, 20, 128)        512       
_________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_1 (TimeDist (None, 5, 20, 128)        49280     
_________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_2 (TimeDist (None, 5, 20, 128)        49280     
_________________________________________________________________
reshape_1 (Reshape)          (None, 20, 640)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_3 (Conv1D)            (None, 20, 128)           245888    
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling1d (MaxPooling1D) (None, 10, 128)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_4 (Conv1D)            (None, 10, 128)           49280     
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling1d_1 (MaxPooling1 (None, 5, 128)            0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_5 (Conv1D)            (None, 5, 128)            49280     
_________________________________________________________________
global_max_pooling1d (Global (None, 128)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 1)                 129       
=================================================================
Total params: 443,649
Trainable params: 443,649
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

**Edit:**

"why you need to reshape and use n_features as the temporal layer"

The reason why n_features needs to be at the temporal layer initially is because Conv1D with dilation and causal padding only works with one feature at a time, and because of how the TimeDistributed layer is implemented.

From their documentation *"Consider a batch of 32 samples, where each sample is a sequence of 10 vectors of 16 dimensions. The batch input shape of the layer is then (32, 10, 16), and the input_shape, not including the samples dimension, is (10, 16).*

*You can then use TimeDistributed to apply a Dense layer to each of the 10 timesteps, independently:"*

By applying the TimeDistributed layer independently to each feature, it reduces the dimension of the problem as if there was only one feature (which would easily allow for dilation and causal padding). With 5 features, they need to each be handled separately at first.

- After your edits this recommendation still applies.
- There shouldn't be a difference in terms of the network whether InputLayer is included in the first layer or separate so you can definitely put it in the first CNN if that resolves the issue.

Comment: I got the model up and running but I'm still unclear on the input shapes. I do not understand why you need to reshape and use n_features as the temporal layer. I might've been unclear with my naming in the original question, so I updated it with an edit. If you could please clarify if your original implementation is still correct after the update? Also, if I use InputLayer and ModelCheckpoint, I'm unable to later load the model back in more on the error here - https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/10417. Not using InputLayer solved the issue for me.

Comment: I wrote a follow up to your question and I would be very grateful if you could check it out and help me one more time. Thank you so much. https://stackoverflow.com/q/56728337/9364931

Comment: There should be a `model.add(Permute(dims=(2, 1)))` before the initial Reshape, otherwise you are unintentionally "shuffling" data from the time and feature dimensions.

Comment: Accordingly there is also a `model.add(Permute(dims=(2, 1, 3)))` missing before the second Reshape.

Comment: @Pedro, I think you are right, and Chris has missed the point. After making reshape, the data are shuffled, so that the number two entry in the new feature becomes the first element of the second original feature, and so on, and all is totally mixed up. Moreover, after Permute we don't need reshape, because the order or dimensions is already (nfeatures, timesteps, 1). Got to test it rigorosuly with small examples...

Comment: Ah yes agreed with Pedro, permute the dims before the first and second reshape.

Answer (score 0):

In `Conv1D` with causal padding is dilation convolution. For `Conv2D` you can use `dilation_rate`  parameter of the Conv2D class. You have to assign `dilation_rate` with 2-tuple of integers. For more information you can read in the [keras documentation](https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/#conv2d) or [here](http://www.erogol.com/dilated-convolution/).

Comment: Thank you. That solves the issue that I can use dilation for Conv2D but even after checking the docs it's unclear to me how I would set the dilation rate specifically to replicate the sequential relationship as with LSTMs and lookback=20 and if my data is shaped correctly as of now to even be able to achieve that.